# Segmentation fault in OpenCV MWE

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get a minimal working example of OpenCV's FABMAP implementation. In order to get there I copied code from [this file](https://github.com/npinto/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/fabmap_sample.cpp). I use a different  OpenCV version than the provider of the sample code (in my case it is 2.4.8) and had to change the original line

```cpp
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor =
    new SurfDescriptorExtractor(1000, 4, 2, false, true);
```

to

```cpp
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor =
    DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");
```

Unfortunately, now I get a segmentation fault that I cannot resolve (I commented the line). Furthermore, I discovered that `extractor` is a nullpointer whereas `matcher` is not. Could it be that the nullpointer `extractor` is causing trouble? How can I resolve this situation?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and g++ for compilation (c++11).

To reproduce this, you would have to download [this directory](https://github.com/npinto/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp/fabmap). My minimal (almost) working example:

```cpp
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    string dataDir = "fabmap_data/";

    FileStorage fs;

    //load/generate vocabulary
    fs.open(dataDir + string("vocab_small.yml"), FileStorage::READ);
    Mat vocab;
    fs["Vocabulary"] >> vocab;
    fs.release();

    //generate test data
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector =
        new DynamicAdaptedFeatureDetector(
        AdjusterAdapter::create("STAR"), 130, 150, 5);
    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor =
        DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF"); // extractor seems to be a nullpointer (addres:: 0x0)
    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher =
        DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");

    BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bide(extractor, matcher);
    bide.setVocabulary(vocab);

    string imageName = "stlucia_test_small0000.jpeg";

    Mat frame;
    Mat bow;
    vector<KeyPoint> kpts;

    frame = imread(dataDir + imageName);
    detector->detect(frame, kpts);
    bide.compute(frame, kpts, bow); // I get a segmentation fault at this line!

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, affecting versions from 2.4.4 to 2.4.9: http://code.opencv.org/issues/2280